# Check if element exists in zig array

Tags: zig

Is there a more idiomatic way of finding if some value is contained in an array than

```
fn valueInArray(value: u32, array: []const u32) bool {
    for (array) |num| {
        if (value == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is generally the most idiomatic solution. It is possible to use [`containsAtLeast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.containsAtLeast) from `std.mem`, but this seems like an abuse of that function (which is really for finding sequences):

```
if (std.mem.containsAtLeast(u32, &my_arr, 1, &[_]u32{42})) {
    std.debug.print("Found it!\n", .{});
} else {
    std.debug.print("No secrets found...\n", .{});
}
```

But I think that the OP posted code could be made more idiomatic by using `comptime` to allow it to accept types other than `u32`:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn inSlice(comptime T: type, haystack: []const T, needle: T) bool {
    for (haystack) |thing| {
        if (thing == needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

pub fn main() void {
    const my_nums = [_]u32{ 1, 2, 3, 42, 5 };
    const my_chars = [_]u8{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'X', 'd' };

    // Check for a `u32` in a slice of `u32`:
    if (inSlice(u32, &my_nums, 42)) {
        std.debug.print("Found the secret!\n", .{});
    } else {
        std.debug.print("No secrets found...\n", .{});
    }

    // Check for a `u8` in a slice of `u8`:
    if (inSlice(u8, &my_chars, 'X')) {
        std.debug.print("'X' marks the spot!\n", .{});
    } else {
        std.debug.print("No treasure found...\n", .{});
    }

    // Check for a character in a string:
    if (inSlice(u8, "Marzipan", 'z')) {
        std.debug.print("Found some delicious marzipan!\n", .{});
    } else {
        std.debug.print("No treats for me...\n", .{});
    }
}
```

```
> .\find_in_array
Found the secret!
'X' marks the spot!
Found some delicious marzipan!
```